# Modify the program that prints the shortest path between two nodes of a graph

Tags: c++, graph-theory, dijkstra

I have a question, how to modify this code that finds the shortest path between two nodes in a graph. This works as it should, but when I have nodes between which there is no path program I immediately break, this condition I set is not printed.

```
void dijkstra2(GRAPH graph, int node,int dest)
{
int previous[MAX];
double distance[MAX]; 
bool Check[MAX]; 
for (int i = 0; i < graph.n; i++) 
{
    distance[i] = INT_MAX, Check[i] = false;
    
}

distance[node] = 0; 
previous[node] = node;
for (int z = 0; z < graph.n - 1; z++)
{
    int md = minimumDistance(graph, distance, Check);
    Check[md] = true;
    
    for (int o = 0; o < graph.n; o++)
    {
        

        if (!Check[o] && graph.ms[md][o] && distance[md] != INT_MAX && distance[md] + graph.ms[md][o] < distance[o])
        {

            distance[o] = distance[md] + graph.ms[md][o];
            previous[o] = md;
            if (o == dest) break;

        }
    }
}

if (node == dest) {
    cout << "The start and end nodes are the same. No need to search for a path." << endl;
    return;
}


int next = dest;



while (next != node) 
{
    cout << next+1 << " <- ";
    next = previous[next]; 
    
}
cout << node + 1;

if (next!=dest) {
    cout << "There is no path between the start and end nodes." << endl;
}

}
```

Comment: How to print "There is no path between the start and end nodes."?

Answer (score 0):

Each time your code visits a node, check if that node is the destination.  If it is, then set a flag true.  On completion, check the flag and if not set then print your message "There is no path between the start and end nodes."

Comment: I don't know where to put it?

Comment: I don't know where to put that flag?

Comment: You could put it in the global namespace.  Or you could declare it as an attribute of your graph class.  Or you could put in as an automatic of your method.  Anywhere really.